# iPhone, C/objC: getting hostname (not by resolving from IP) by hooking into system wide functions?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm currently writing an MobileSubstrate plugin (code injection for iPhone). It gets the hostname by hooking into connect() and this piece of code:

```
#ifndef   NI_MAXHOST
#define   NI_MAXHOST 1025
#endif

int error;

 char hostname[NI_MAXHOST] = "";


 error = getnameinfo(serv_addr, addrlen, hostname, NI_MAXHOST, NULL, 0, 0);

 if (error !=0) {
  ALogTCP(@"coudldn't resolve hostname or internal connect");

  return orig__connect(sockfd, serv_addr, addrlen);
  }


 if (error == 0) {
  ALogTCP(@"hostname: %s", hostname);
  NSString *hostFirst = [NSString stringWithCString:hostname];
}
```

Now I've noticed that some hostnames won't get resolved properly (wrong host: like connect.xyz.com instead of irc.xyz.com)  (depending on the DNS Server).

I'm not very used to all the networking functions and an extensive search didn't turn up any solution.:
I'm thinking about hooking into a function which is responsible for all hostname->IP "conversions", getting the hostname and use it later in the above code. Is there such a function? and how is it called?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: That's a pretty confusing question. If nothing is capable of resolving your IP into a host name, then it simply doesn't have one that would be meaningful enough to worry about. Are you asking for the name that Bonjour automatically assigns itself?

Comment: no, I'm asking about the C function which is responsible for resolving hostnames to IP. cause I wanna hook into it (inject code) 

For example if an app uses NSURLConnection, in the background connect() is used to establish the connection (which I'm already hooking. But before connect() the hostname has to be resolved to an IP (for servaddr). I wanna know which function does that so I can hook into it too

Comment: The short answer is there is no "one" function that does this, nor any requirement that an app use the system provided `resolver` functions.

Comment: But there must be a function/method which is responsible for resolving of hostnames (in the background) which gets called when for example NSURLConnection is used

Comment: Sure, but there's multiple ways to do it.  An app doesn't even have to use the system provided resolver functions, it can use a third party resolver library (see `c-ares` http://c-ares.haxx.se/ which provides asynchronous DNS resolution)  Are you trying to intercept all DNS resolution function calls so you can manipulate the result that is returned?  Or do you just want to perform DNS resolution for an address for a given socket for your own use?  It's not clear from your question what, exactly, you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to intercept all DNS resulution calls. to get the hostname before connect() is used so I can create a dictionary with them. I'm coding a firewall for iPhone and the reverse hostname is sometimes wrong (because of DNS servers). And I doubt there are many apps who use 3rd party resolver. 

I debugged an own little app which is using NSURLConnections and tried to break on all resolver routines but it didn't break. Cocoa must use something different and that's what I'm trying to find.

Hopefully my question is now a bit clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how I finally did it, took me only about 7 hours to figure it out :D

1. hooking into CFHostCreateWithName(CFAllocatorRef *allocator, CFStringRef *hostname)
2. after that I use gethostbyname to get the IP.

now I can compare that information with the one I retrieve by hooking into connect()